# What is causing OOM here

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wcf, out-of-memory

I have a .NET 3.5 web application which allows users to generate PDF reports of various set of custom data. The reports are generated through a web service call on a separate report generator server (also a .NET WCF service) using JSON. The web application caches the binary data of the report locally in a MySQL database for a configurable temporary period of time so if the same report is requested again, it is served from the local cache. The WCF contract of the generated report response is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class GetReportBase64EncodedReply
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Base64EncodedFile { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Md5 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Size { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

At the receiving end (web application) the report is received as the above contract as a Base64 encoded string and is processed as follows:

```
GetReportBase64EncodedReply reportResult = (GetReportBase64EncodedReply)serviceResponse.Data;
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(reportResult.Base64EncodedFile);
var expiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(180);
var cachedReport = new LocalDbStorageAction.Insert(bytes, expiryDate);
```

It has been running fine for a while and now throwing a system out of memory exception on the last line when trying to insert the binary data into the local database. Also can not reproduce this in development. I am considering the following but need a bit of guidance:

1. The whole report is being downloaded at once as a base64 string
   which could be changed to a sequential download.
2. Holding the entire byte array in memory before storing it locally which could be changed to a temporary file that is appended to using
   Step 1 and once the transfer is complete, read the file (e.g.
   File.ReadAllBytes()) and store in the local database.

How different is it in memory usage to make the Change 1 and/or 2?
Is there a way to do a sequential SQL INSERT (similar to sequential reads i.e. GetBytes() and GetChars()) and if so is that recommended here?

Comment: You've got a memory leak somewhere. Your program is hanging on to references to some objects (maybe your `reportResult` or `cachedReport` items and maybe something else) and not releasing them to the garbage collector. Streaming data to MySQL LOBs is a pain in the neck. You probably should find the memory leak first. Better yet, build your classes with `IDisposable` , implement the `Dispose()` method for them, and refer to instances of those classes in `using(){}` clauses.

Comment: @Ollie: Thanks. I will implement IDisposable for these classes.